# RobotFramework : scope of variables

Tags: variables, robotframework

I have a problem with the ${testAccount} variable.
When I modify this variable in the user keyword "Modify user name", the Log informs me that the modification is correct.
When I use this variable in the keyword "Change activation", it is equal to the initial value and not the modified one.

Here is the script I wrote :

```
*** Keywords ***
Modify user name  
    Set Global Variable    ${testAccount}
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//a[@ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]  
    Click Element    //td[text()='${testAccount}']/following-sibling::td//a[@ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]  
    Wait Until Page Contains    Edit an account  
    Click Element    xpath=//input[@ng-model="tenant.name"]    
    Press Key    xpath=//input[@ng-model="tenant.name"]    \\08  
    ${testAccount}=    Get Substring    ${testAccount}    \    -1
    Click Button    xpath=//button[@ng-click="valid()"]  
    Wait Until Page Contains    ${testAccount}

Change activation  
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//a[@ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]  
    Click Element    //td[text()='${testAccount}']/following-sibling::td//a[@ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]
```

I tried to use the keywords 'Set Global Variable' or 'Set Suite Variable', but it doesn't work any better. Maybe I don't use them properly.

Could you, please, help me understand ?

Comment: Could you provide example where you tried to use `Set Suite Variable` or `Set Global Variable`? In attached screenshot `${testAccount}` variable in `Modify user name` keyword  is local and is visible only inside this keyword.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. They are useless because the code won't show up in a search, and we can't copy and paste it. Take the time to properly copy, paste, and format  your code directly in the question.

Comment: Have you read the user guide section [Variable priorities and scope](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-priorities-and-scopes)?

Comment: I modified my request as desired in the comments

Comment: This is a very interesting document that I will keep to one side. Unless I am mistaken, I do not seem to have read any information related to my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the 'Set Global Variable' keyword after the line that modifies the contents of the variable ${testAccount}. Thus the new content of this variable will be taken into account in the following testcase until it changes again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set Suite Variable Keyword.

Follow the below link 
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Suite%20Variable

Also use Return Statement at the end of first Keyword 'Modify user name' and use the variable '${testAccount}' as an argument in the second keyword 'Change activation'

Check the code below.

```
Modify user name  
  Set Suite Variable   ${testAccount}
  Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//a[@ng- 
  click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]  
  Click Element    //td[text()='${testAccount}']/following-sibling::td//a[@ng- 
  click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]  
  Wait Until Page Contains    Edit an account  
  Click Element    xpath=//input[@ng-model="tenant.name"]    
  Press Key    xpath=//input[@ng-model="tenant.name"]    \\08  
  ${testAccount}=    Get Substring    ${testAccount}    \    -1
  Click Button    xpath=//button[@ng-click="valid()"]  
  Wait Until Page Contains    ${testAccount}

  Return   ${testAccount}
```

`Change activation     ${testAccount}`

```
 Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//a[@ng-click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]  
 Click Element    //td[text()='${testAccount}']/following-sibling::td//a[@ng- 
 click="openCreateEditModal(tenant)"]
```